# How to access and destroy the canvas using ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I have a canvas in a react component. I have used react refs to access the node and added a destroy() method to it. Instead I get a error

```
TypeError: canvasRef.current.destroy is not a function
```

How can we access the node(canvas) using react refs and destroy that canvas?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js";

export default function WaterFallChart() {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef();

  if (canvasRef.current) {
      canvasRef.current.destroy();
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="canvasParentDiv">
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Below is the section of my changes

```
export default function WaterFallChart(props) {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = new Chart(canvasRef.current, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thurs", "fri"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Good",
            data: props.data,
     
          }
        ]
      },
    });
    return () => {
      chart.destroy();
    };
  }, [props.data]);
  return (
    <div className="canvasParentDiv">
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is this destroy() function you're trying to use? I don't see it in canvas docs on MDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destroy` is not a method on [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement), but if you just want to remove the `<canvas>` from the DOM, you don't need to worry about that. React will automatically remove the `<canvas>` element from the DOM when the WaterFallChart component is unmounted.

If you're using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), then [`destroy` is a method on the Chart object](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy), not on the canvas. You would still probably call this in the cleanup function of an effect, not in the component body.

```
export default function WaterFallChart() {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Code here will run after canvasRef.current has
    // been populated with the HTMLCanvasElement, this
    // is where you would create the Chart object.
    const chart = new Chart(canvasRef.current, ...);

    // You probably don't want to destroy the chart
    // until the component is unmounting, so you would
    // return it as the effect's cleanup function:
    return () => {
      chart.destroy();
    }
  }, [])

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I am using Chart.js, but effect clean up function destroys the Chart and I don't see any data on the chart.

`return () => {chart.destroy();}`

Comment: @madhavkoirala Try making your component look like the sample I gave, I think that's probably what you want. You'd create the Chart in the effect, and return a function that destroys the Chart.

Comment: I have added my section. I do have created a Chart in the effect and then called a function to destroy the old chart when data changes. But still I do get my charts empty.

Comment: Thank you so much. I find effect clean up function really powerful.